# Provisioning Profilesを誤って削除してしまいました。

Tags: swift, xcode

MacOSとXcodeをアップデートした際、iPhoneの実機テストができなくなりました。
そこで、
Xcode起動
アップルマークの右隣りXcodeクリック
２段目のPreferences...をクリック
左から２番めのAccountsをクリック
右下のView Details...をクリック
の後のページの左下にある、
Download Allをクリックしたところ、
Provisioning Prolisseが消えてしまいました。

なので、当然ながら
No provisioning profiles found: No non-expired Provisioning profiles were found.
とメッセージが出て、ビルドすらできなくなってしまいました。

誰か助けて下さい。
お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gitは使用していないのでしょうか？
他のファイルを新規作成して追加はできませんか？

Comment: Githubは使っていません。新規作成しても状況は変わりません。iOS Developer で３つのファイルをDLしてみました（iOSTeam Provisioning Profile.        iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: co...        Users iPhone  です。３つのファイルをXcodeのアイコンに重ねてみましたが、状況はかわりませんでした。